# Formatting error with source code on WordPress.com?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, code, formatting

I've been trying to [post](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) some Java code to my blog, but it seems like it has some problems with the formatting.

First, whenever I copy/paste code into the editor, it's pasted as pre-formatted, which means that it converts the indents to spaces, all on a single line.

And when I try to separate the lines by making each line of code on a single physical line, it doesn't indent them automatically.

I'm using the visual editor, and I've checked the HTML code, and nothing seems to be wrong with it.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug I should report to WordPress?

Comment: Format the code in a proper text editor first, then just paste it inside the shortcode once you're done. I post code to my WP.com blog without a problem.

Comment: I copied the code to gedit, and I still have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the code in the HTML editor, it probably won't try to convert indents and linebreaks. Surround it with the `[sourcecode]` shortcode and only then return to the visual editor.